# Input not working Python

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm making a candy box game, but i cant get the input to work. The other problem is it prints 'You have 1 sweet.' and then stops. Please help?

```
import time, sys
print("Sweetie box")
sweets = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    sweets += 1
    print("You have ", sweets, " sweets.")
    INPUT = input()
    if INPUT == ("a"):
            print("It worked!")
```

Comment: You need to *call* the function `input()`.

Comment: Sounds like you want the number of sweets to continuously update, even while waiting for the user to make a move. That's not very easy to do on the command line with just built-in functions. Perhaps you should consider a UI lib like Tkinter -- then you could update your labels every second while still watching buttons/text boxes for input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the `input` built-in by adding `()` after it:

```
INPUT = input()
```

Right now, you have `INPUT` being set to the built-in *itself*.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> x = input
>>> x
<built-in function input>
>>> x = input()
word
>>> x
'word'
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've just edited with a second problem

Comment: @user2916424 - If you are seeing what I think you are, then that is the input prompt.  You have to enter something and then press ENTER.  I tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: i get that you have to press enter, it's just the sweets should update without having to have an input. D'ya know what's wrong?

Comment: @user2916424 - Hmm.  I ran this in Python 3.3 and `sweets` _did_ update.  Just, you had to enter something first.  If you don't want an input, why not remove it altogether?